# version mismatch error for management console app for hazelcast v2.5

Tags: hazelcast

I switched over to 2.5 recently.  I just tried the management console (v2.5) for hazelcast (running in tomcat7) - I believe the app directory is readable/writable.  I have a hazelcast node running (same version).  However, the connection request is failing complaining about version mismatch even though they are the same versions (error copied below).  Any suggestions to troubleshoot this would be most welcome.

```
com.hazelcast.impl.management.VersionMismatchLogRequest
SEVERE: [192.168.1.11]:5701 [dev] Version Mismatch
    management center version : 2.5
    hazelcast version : 2.5
```

Comment: as far as i know management center 2.5 only supports up to v2.41 silly i know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting plenty of egg on my face these days.  Pilot error.  These are the steps I followed:

1. Switched from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 (localhost on my box is 0.0.0.0)
2. More importantly, ensured that the data directory for mancenter (called mancenter) was in /var/lib/tomcat7 and was readable/writable - it was not the case earlier.

Username/pwd (default) is admin/admin.
So far, it works.  Hope it helps!